# WebDAV SabreDAV and HTTPS

Tags: javascript, php, curl, webdav, sabredav

I'm trying to connect to an HTTPS sitefrom a PHP page I'm writing, I've tried to usa SabreDAV but I have the error because it requires the SSL certificate. Is there any way to make SabreDav skip the certificate verification? I need to access the 2nd page of the site where a filelist to donwload is.

I've also tried with cURL, it helps skipping verification but I cannot access the next page where the filelist to download is.

Maybe there's also a javascript invovled in the login form... this is the site I have the credentials of:

https://asp.gigacc.com/user/sony-dc-cert

thanks in advance, please give me some hint